# How to use _configthreadlocale in MinGW

Tags: mingw, setlocale

I want to do something like

```
_configthreadlocale(_ENABLE_PER_THREAD_LOCALE);
```

However, I'm getting the error

> '_ENABLE_PER_THREAD_LOCALE' undeclared

Comment: What version of MinGW are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You need to include locale.h if you want to use this function.

If your version of locale.h does not contain this function, you'll need to exchange your MinGW.org installation for a MinGW-w64 installation. It does the same thing, only better. Get it through [the installer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win32/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/installer/mingw-w64-install.exe/download), or [MSYS2](http://msys2.github.io/) (a Unix shell based on Cygwin and the package manager pacman, you'll need to install the proper compiler through e.g. `pacman -S mingw-w64-{i686,x86_64}-gcc`).

MinGW.org (the version you cite, 3.21.0, gives it away) is outdated when it comes to features and API completeness. I highly recommend you leave it behind in favour of MinGW-w64 based tools. Almost all open source projects have done so.

Comment: I'm using MinGW 3.21.0.

I tried including locale.h from the mingw\include folder, it doesn't have _configurethreadlocale, just 

setlocale and localeconv.

Comment: Thanks, I now have MinGW-w64 and am using that version of build tools, and including the right <locale.h>.  I'm still getting this on link, any idea?

undefined reference to `_configthreadlocal